# Multiply values from text of elements on runtime-protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

In my application, i have a value populated during runtime.

```
<span id="uxUnitPrice">182.18</span>
```

I want to extract this unit price and multiply against a fixed value for e.g. 15.
Once i get the result on screen i want to fetch that and compare to see if calculation done by me matches what is displayed on screen.
For e.g. result should be 182.18*15=2732.25
I tried below code but it is giving me NaN. Can someone please suggest how to perform a mathematical operation correctly using Selenium or protractor?

```
MeltValueCoin = element(by.css('[id="uxUnitPrice"]'));
expect(ValidateMeltValueCalculator()).tobe(2732.25);
function ValidateMeltValueCalculator(){
      var units = 10;
      var MeltValue = parseInt(MeltValueCoin.getText());
      return units*MeltValue;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getText` returns a promise. Thus you first need to resolve it with `then` to get the value:

```
MeltValueCoin = element(by.css('[id="uxUnitPrice"]'));

expect(ValidateMeltValueCalculator()).tobe(2732.25);

function ValidateMeltValueCalculator(){
    var units = 10;
    return MeltValueCoin.getText().then(text => text * units);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest how should I limit it to 2 decimal digits?If i multiple it by 10, this is returning me 1822.1000000000001

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: I tried toFixed already. It is showing me that  "Failed: result.toFixed is not a function". I also tried below but this is giving me 'Expected NaN to be 2733.15'.
`var result = MeltValueCoin.getText().then(text=>text*units);
return Math.round(result * 100) / 100'

Comment: From your comment `result` is a promise, so you can't round it. Try this instead: `return MeltValueCoin.getText().then(text => Math.round(text * units * 100) / 100);`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Below usage works better for me. `return MeltValueCoin.getText().then(text => (text * units).toFixed(2));`

Comment: Congrats on reaching the deserved 10k!